# Assigning a number to category

Tags: r

I have to assign an ID to the sentences that contain specific words.

Below is the  R dataframe that contains ID's for each location. I need to scan this:

```
Place       ID
Ladakh      12
Mumbai      14
Bangalore   17
```

I have another data frame that contains the following sentences:

Description

```
Vinod is coming to Ladakh
Rahul is coming to Mumbai
```

For example, I need the output as below (basically column `Place` should extract information from `Description` column):

```
Description                 Place   ID
Vinod is coming to Ladakh   Ladakh  12
Rahul is coming to Mumbai   Mumbai  14
```

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please provide a *reproducible* example.

Comment: Apologies and I have edited

Comment: Request you to guide me on this

Comment: Use `dput` with the data frames used here. And add the result to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 = read.table(text = "
Place      ID
Ladakh     12
Mumbai     14
Bangalore  17
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

df2 = data.frame(Description = c("Vinod is coming to Ladakh",
                                 "Rahul is coming to Mumbai"),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

library(tidyverse)

df2 %>%
  mutate(Place = Description) %>%
  separate_rows(Place) %>%
  inner_join(df1, by="Place")

#                 Description  Place ID
# 1 Vinod is coming to Ladakh Ladakh 12
# 2 Rahul is coming to Mumbai Mumbai 14
```